# Removing IE's scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, scrollbar

First of all, I don't want to just remove  it, I want to ensure that there is still scrolling capabilities there also.

This is because I would like to have a 'slide show' affect on the website, where you can click 'next' and before, however with the scroll bar there, you can just go through it.

I have hidden the scrollbar in other browsers using:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

for webkit browsers and `overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;` for Firefox. However, when it comes to IE, I can't find anything to simply hide it.

I found these on the internet:

```
scrollbar-3dlight-color:;
scrollbar-arrow-color:;
scrollbar-base-color:;
scrollbar-darkshadow-color:;
scrollbar-face-color:;
scrollbar-highlight-color:;
scrollbar-shadow-color:;
```

I thought by changing the colour to `transparent`, it would disappear, but it did not (just reverts back to normal).

Is there a way I can simply hide the scrollbar (simply like `display:none` or something else), in IE? I am open to `css` and `js` options.

[jsFiddle of problem](http://jsfiddle.net/SKu45/)

**NOTE:** Adding `overflow:hidden;` stops the page from going past the second `div` when clicking the `a` tag.

Comment: Your edit shows a severe lack of both understanding the provided answer and proper use of the shift / caps lock key.

Comment: I bolded it because I didn't want that answer @PeeHaa

Comment: As I stated: lack of understanding

Comment: I find this post quite offensive as the bold capital text feels quite shouty, we're here to help, not to take commands, if you need to explain something simply make your question clear instead of going bold-capslock mode.

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand, it's hard to convey how I am saying it. It's not that I am shouting, I just wanted to state that I wanted another method other than `overflow:hidden;`. Sorry.

Comment: @PeeHaa, If I use overflow:hidden, I can no longer use my mousewheel to get to off-screen elements. I still want to use my mousewheel to get around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [See here for fiddle using your current code](http://jsfiddle.net/X535y/)

Try [this trick](http://jsfiddle.net/eYeth/)

```
body, div, html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
}
div{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    position:relative;
    right:-20px;
}
```

It offsets a scrollable div so its vertical scrollbar is outside the viewable area.

Comment: I know this, but this prevents scrolling on the page. I still want to be able to scroll, just without scrollbars showing (using `a` tags to name's and scrolling)

Comment: You can try adding: <body scroll="no">

Comment: Tried that, I'll update the question, that didn't do anything.

Comment: If I do `overflow:hidden;` and use an `a` tag to go to a div off the page, the page wont scroll.

Comment: @BeatAlex - I've updated with another example, which uses a CSS trick to hide the scrollbar

Comment: @ExtPro here is a jsFiddle of what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/SKu45/ I just want the scrollbar to disappear whilst still using the mousewheel to get around

Comment: @ExtPro Yes and when I get to the second div, it stops working, similarly to `overflow:hidden;`.

Comment: Maybe I should close this and open another question as to why `overflow:hidden;` stops working after the second div scroll? That might be easier to understand?

Comment: There is no second div in the fiddle I've posted.

Comment: Yes, but when I apply this method to MY jsFiddle, it wont go past the second div.

Comment: I'm going to open another question which will be clearer. Thank you for trying to help me. I'll give you a +1 but since it wasn't the answer, I can't accept.

Comment: @BeatAlex - fixed...this was annoying me so I worked on it, please see revised answer

Answer (score 3):

I have similar problem, I don't need scroll bars on main page, but i have to have inside of my page content like in div's and span's.

So I found solution like this:

```
body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
div, span {
    -ms-overflow-style: auto;
}
```