# Disable scrollbar instead of hiding in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

My requirement is to disable scrollbar instead of hiding.

I followed the below post:

[Just disable scroll not hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it)

It is working fine with Chrome & FF. But it is not working in IE. Still am able to scroll in IE.

Can anyone suggest me a workaround for IE browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242608/disable-browsers-vertical-and-horizontal-scrollbars

Comment: @JacekKowalewski I want to disable the scroll bar not hiding

Comment: Check this out:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806680/disable-scroll-bar-in-ie]

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241387/removing-ies-scrollbar]